# My Treeset only adds 1 class object

Tags: java, collections, treeset

I'm trying to add the below book objects to a TreeSet. However, when I debug the code, it says that the set has a size of 1 and only contains the first object added (book1). When I comment out book1, book2 is the only one added etc. 
 Why is it that the JVm only recognises one object?

**Code:**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Book> bookSet = new TreeSet<Book>();

    Book book1 = new Book("Digital Fortress", "Dan Brown", "St. Martins Press", 1998);
    Book book2 = new Book("Angels and Demons", "Dan Brown", "Pocket Books", 2000);
    Book book3 = new Book("Deception Point", "Dan Brown", "Pocket Books", 2001);
    Book book4 = new Book("The Davinci Code", "Dan Brown", "DoubleDay", 2003);
    Book book5 = new Book("The Lost Symbol", "Dan Brown", "DoubleDay", 2009);
    Book book6 = new Book("Inferno", "Dan Brown", "DoubleDay", 2013);

    bookSet.add(book1);
    bookSet.add(book2);
    bookSet.add(book3);
    bookSet.add(book4);
    bookSet.add(book5);
    bookSet.add(book6);

    System.out.println(bookSet);
}
```

Here is the entire code so far (It has to be all in the same class):

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Iterator;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Set;
  import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Book implements Comparable<Book> {

String title;
String author;
String publisher;
int publicationYear;

List<String> authorList = new ArrayList<String>();

public Book(String title, String author, String publisher, int publicationYear){
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.publisher = publisher;
    this.publicationYear = publicationYear;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public List<String> getAuthorList() {
    return authorList;
}

public void setAuthorList(List<String> authorList) {
    this.authorList = authorList;
}

public String getPublisher() {
    return publisher;
}

public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
    this.publisher = publisher;
}

public int getPublicationYear() {
    return publicationYear;
}

public void setPublicationYear(int publicationYear) {
    this.publicationYear = publicationYear;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}


public String toString(){   
    return "Book Title: " + getTitle() + "\nAuthor Name: " + getAuthor() + "\nPublisher: " + getPublisher() + "\nYear of Publication: " + getPublicationYear();  
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Book> bookSet = new TreeSet<Book>();

    Book book1 = new Book("Digital Fortress", "Dan Brown", "St. Martins Press", 1998);
    Book book2 = new Book("Angels and Demons", "Dan Brown", "Pocket Books", 2000);
    Book book3 = new Book("Deception Point", "Dan Brown", "Pocket Books", 2001);
    Book book4 = new Book("The Davinci Code", "Dan Brown", "DoubleDay", 2003);
    Book book5 = new Book("The Lost Symbol", "Dan Brown", "DoubleDay", 2009);
    Book book6 = new Book("Inferno", "Dan Brown", "DoubleDay", 2013);

    bookSet.add(book1);
    bookSet.add(book2);
    bookSet.add(book3);
    bookSet.add(book4);
    bookSet.add(book5);
    bookSet.add(book6);

    System.out.println(bookSet);
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Book o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: please provide a Book class code

Comment: A TreeSet relies on code within your **Book** class to do its job (like calling equals/hashCode methods of that class). So, most likely, your **implementation** of those methods isn't as it should be. You want to read stuff like http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/hashcode-equals.html for example

Comment: `TODO Auto-generated method stub`. Should replace that with actual code..

Answer (score 3):

All books are equal to one another (evident by returning 0). A `Set` cannot contain duplicates, so that's why only one (the first Book) is ever added

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Book o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

You need to fill in the details of the method. Negative numbers say `this` book is less than `o`, vice versa for positive numbers

Comment: To be fair to the OP, the [Javadoc for `add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add-E-) says that an element will only be added if the set doesn't already contain one that `equals()` this element. This is wrong. It should say if it doesn't contain an element for which `compareTo()` returns 0. It is [not required](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) that `compareTo` and `equals` are consistent. If the TreeSet did indeed use `equals()` then the OP's code should have worked.

Comment: Sure, but if you read the rest of the docs. *a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal.*

Comment: You're right, the TreeSet documentation states that `compareTo()` must be consistent with `equals()` for all elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Book o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

What `Comparable#compareTo` return value says -

> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less
>   than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.
>   [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-)

When you added multiple object to tree set, a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal.All the object are equals by `Book` objects `compareTo` method(provided) definition, so TreeSet just ignored duplicate object.

**Solution**:
Define compareTo method correctly, keeping this thing in mind return value should 
 negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Answer (score 1):

Update your compareTo method based on your requirement. Or at least update as below, it will allow to insert all objects in treeset.

```
public int compareTo(Book o) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return this.compareTo(o);
}
```